# Python - create a class as index for 2-dimension numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, class, indexing, jupyter

I have some code of index class `TwoDimIndex`. I wanna use it to indexes of numpy 2-dimension array like `arr[idx]`. Below is code of that class.

```
import numpy as np

class TwoDimIndex:
    def __init__(self, i1, i2):
        self.i1 = i1
        self.i2 = i2
        pass

    def __index__(self):
        return self.i1, self.i2 
        # return np.array([self.i1, self.i2]) - Tried this too
        
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.i1 == other
        
    def __int__(self):
        return self.i1
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__int__())

# Don't edit code of this function please
def useful_func():
    idx = TwoDimIndex(1, 1) # Can edit create instance
    arr_two_dim = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
    print(idx.__index__() == (1, 1))
    print(arr_two_dim[1, 1], arr_two_dim[idx.__index__()]) # Success
    print(arr_two_dim[idx]) # Crash here
    # But I want this code work!!!

useful_func()
```

Class `TwoDimIndex` is use to be index, for example `arr[TwoDimIndex()]`.

All code for Jupyter Notebook and Python 3.8. But I get error when execute this code.

`` IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices ``

Is there any ways to make an instance of a class `TwoDimIndex` an numpy 2-d array index?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Hello. If you use my code, you will gain minimal example. I wanna to work `print(arr_two_dim[idx])` code.

Comment: `idx = np.s_[ 1, 1 ]` creates a slice into the first 2 dimensions of a numpy array but idx = ( 1, 1 ) will work for integer slice values too.

Comment: I wanna have instance of my own class instead of having edition of part `useful_func`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find short solution with inherit from tuple.

```
class TwoDimIndex(tuple):
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.tup = tuple(tup)
        pass

    def __index__(self):
        return self.tup

def useful_func():
    idx = TwoDimIndex([1, 1]) # Edit at create class
    arr_two_dim = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])
    print(idx.__index__() == (1, 1))
    print(arr_two_dim[1, 1], arr_two_dim[idx.__index__()]) # Success
    print(arr_two_dim[idx]) # Success now

useful_func()
```

Not sure it is right way but it work.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone try this before, and don't know why you'd want it.  But as you found, indexing is particular about the nature of the object.  It needs to be a tuple, and contain elements as listed in the IndexingError.  The classes in `np.lib.intex_tricks` (eg `np.s_`) give an idea of how an index expression is processed.